# On the unique factorisation of $R[x_1,y_1,...,x_n,y_n]/(x_1y_1+...+x_ny_n)$ where $R$ is UFD

Tags: commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a Noetherian UFD.

Then how to show that for every integer $n\ge 3$, the ring $A_n:= R[x_1,y_1,...,x_n,y_n]/(x_1y_1+...+x_ny_n)$ is a UFD ?

I'm not even sure how to show $A_n$ is an integral domain ...

Please help.

Comment: Your ring is $A=S[f/x_1], S=R[x_1,..,x_n,y_2,...,y_n], f=x_2y_2+...+x_ny_n$. It is an integral domain. $S$ is an UFD, if $u \in S$ is irreducible then $uS$ is prime, if $u\not \in x_1 S+fS$ then $uA$ is prime. Thus it remains to check the primes contained in $x_1 A+f/x_1 A$. $n\ge 3$ is needed for $x_1 A$ and $f/x_1 A$ to be prime.

Comment: This is an immediate application of [Nagata's criterion for factoriality](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFU).

Comment: @user26857 can you explain how to use Nagata's criterion to show $R$ is an integral domain?

Comment: @Youngsu I suppose a criterion for factoriality is for proving factoriality, not for proving the ring is an integral domain (which is almost trivial in this case).

Comment: @user26857: could you please give some pointers on how to apply Nagata's criterion here ?

Comment: Use the multiplicative set generated by $x_n$.